# Implement glow filter in CV2 Python

Tags: python, opencv

Goal is to implement the GLOW implementation in cv2 with Python3 from this site: https://pinetools.com/glow-effect-image.

The current implementation is written in javascript and can be found in this repo:
https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic/blob/fa4b9283f0a57c677d0f6762933bdfe5b0714242/pixastic.effects.js#L587 under glow.

My knowledge of javascript is very limited, so I don't understand what the steps of the algorithm are. Hope that someone can help.

I tried:

```
IMAGE_PATH = 'path'

img_org = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH, 1)
gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_org,(3,3),1)


b,g,r = cv2.split(gaussian)
b_n = b + 0*100
g_n = g + 1*100
r_n = r + 2*100

if r_n.any() > 255:
    r_n = 255
if g_n.any() > 255:
    g_n = 255
if b_n.any() > 255:
    b_n= 255

merged = cv2.merge([b_n, g_n, r_n])
concatted = np.concatenate((img_org, merged), axis=1)

cv2.imshow('final', concatted)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Example pict

[image: example pict]

Desired result

[image: desired result]

My result

[image: my result]

But as you can see the results are way off. Can somebody help?

**EDIT - explanation of accepted answer**

Thanks AKX and Aron. I tested both of your solutions and the result can be found here (left Aron, Right AKX). The solution of AKX was precisely like the one in the example. Thank you both.

[image]

Comment: what is your code even doing? please explain. I need to see if you know what you're doing.

Comment: No I don't, thats the main problem. I don't understand the code and underlying theory that was written in javascript. I tried to translate that to Py, but as you can see I failed doing so. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is blurring the image, then adding the blurred version to the original image.

This can be done in a couple of lines using OpenCV.

You can adjust the glow strength and radius with the variables given.

```
import cv2

source_path = '4wJqC.jpg'
glow_strength = 1  # 0: no glow, no maximum
glow_radius = 25  # blur radius

img = cv2.imread(source_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (glow_radius, glow_radius), 1)
img_blended = cv2.addWeighted(img, 1, img_blurred, glow_strength, 0)

cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', img_blended)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use matrix multiplication. Hope this helps:

```
## Import packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
%matplotlib inline 

## Parameters
IMAGE_PATH = 'plate.jpg'
param_resize = 2000 

# Read the image
img_org = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)

# Resize based on the parameters
img_org = cv2.resize(img_org, (param_resize,param_resize))

# Gausian
gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_org,(3,3),1)

## Split the gausian and the orginal image
b_gaus,g_gaus,r_gaus = cv2.split(gaussian)
b,g,r = cv2.split(img_org)

## Matrix multiplication 
##### When reading in with cv2 then the type is uint8, which means the range is max 255
calculated_b_array = b_gaus.astype(int) + b.astype(int)
calculated_g_array = g_gaus.astype(int) + g.astype(int)
calculated_r_array = r_gaus.astype(int) + r.astype(int)

## If the pixelvalue is higher than 255, set it to 255
calculated_b_array[calculated_b_array > 255] = 255
calculated_g_array[calculated_g_array > 255] = 255
calculated_r_array[calculated_r_array > 255] = 255

## Merge for visualization purposes
merged = cv2.merge([calculated_b_array, calculated_g_array, calculated_r_array])
concatted = np.concatenate((img_org, merged), axis=1)

## Save the image
cv2.imwrite('plate_output.jpeg', concatted)
```

See the results in this link:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aYwb.jpg)

Comment: What's with the resizing of the image? The original code doesn't have that.

Comment: The orginal code was a loop trough all the pixels, since that was slow my first solution was  resizing the image. But then I changed the code to matrix manipulation.